# efficient chunking with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I'm using a pandas frame, which can contain loads of content, and for each of the documents I need to get some defined noun phrases. Though everything works it is also kind of slow, and I'm sure there are better ways to achieve the same results but my python knowledge is not good enough.

So any advice on how to improve would be highly appreciated.

This is my code :

```
import pandas
import nltk, re
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, regexp_tokenize, wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk.chunk import *
from nltk.chunk.util import *
from nltk.chunk.regexp import *
from nltk import untag

def chunckMe(str,rule):

    np=[]
    chunk_parser = RegexpChunkParser(rule, chunk_label='LBL')
    sentences= sent_tokenize(str)

    for sent in sentences:
        d_words=nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
        d_tagged=nltk.pos_tag(d_words)
        chunked_text = chunk_parser.parse(d_tagged)

        tree = chunked_text
        for subtree in tree.subtrees():
            if subtree.label() == 'LBL': np.append(" ".join(untag(subtree)).lower())

    return np;

# main def
def rm_main(data):

    np_all=[]

    # This works but can probably be done much better ...

    for index,row in data.iterrows():

        str=row["txt"]

        chunk_rule = ChunkRule("<JJ.*><NN.*>+|<JJ.*>*<NN.*><CC>*<NN.*>+|<CD><NN.*>", "Simple noun phrase")
        tags = chunckMe(str,[chunk_rule])
        np_all.append(', '.join(set(tags)))

    data['noun_phrases']=np_all

    return data
```

Any idea how I could avoid or improve the iterrows part? it works but I have the strong feeling there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So for what you (or should I say we, I found you post so thank you!!!) are trying to accomplish, I personally think how you are doing it is actually pretty good. I was having an issue with figuring out how to have the chunking parse through a data frame and this is brilliant. From my data science textbook and course, the following code is the best practice for lists. Your code is not only more efficient (for 2k rows mine took over 5 minutes yours parsed the same data in a DF in less than 1 minute) but works for data frames!

```
CHUNK_01 = r"""NAMES :{<NNP><NNP>}"""
results = []
for sentence in data:
    sentence_results = []
    for s in sentence:
        sentence_results.append(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
    results.append(sentence_results)

tagged = nltk.pos_tag(results)                
CP_01 = nltk.RegexpParser(CHUNK_01)
c01 = CP_01.parse( tagged )

chunks = []
i = 0
for x in c01:
    if type(x) == nltk.tree.Tree :
        x = str(x)
        chunks.append(x,i)
```